# My leaf texture repeats itself, how to stop it?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am making some trees and the leaf texture won't work properly below are images of it:

[image: leaf texture]
as you can see the texture is repeating

The UV map is below:

[image: UV map]
The above mess is the UV map

how do I make the UV proper so that each plane has one leaf texture?

Comment: For each leaf to display one single leaf texture, all UVs should be placed on this texture. I guess in your case the easiest way would be to select all faces in the viewport by pressing A, then U > Unwrap > Reset.

Comment: It worked @GordonBrinkmann thanks

Comment: I'll give it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each leaf to display one single leaf texture, all UVs should be placed on this texture. Your screenshot shows, that the leaves' UVs are scattered all over the place and sized differently. I guess in your case the easiest way would be to select all faces in the viewport by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap* > *Reset*.